# What does it mean to check that a parameter is not null or empty nor negative?

Tags: java

I have an assignment where it says

> The parameters must be checked to ensure they are not null or empty nor a negative value.

I am having trouble understanding what checking to ensure they are not null or empty nor negative means.

```
//field 
private String listingNumber;




//My constructor:

public A0_Realtor(String listingNumberParam)
{        
        setListingNumber(listingNumberParam);
}
```

Setter that compiles but doesn't work? if a create a default constructor and check the value, I find that the value is null and doesn't print out invalid value

```
//Getter not sure if this does anything

public String getListingNumber(){
        return listingNumber;
}

//Setter

public void setListingNumber(String newListingNumber){

        if( newListingNumber != null || newListingNumber.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Invalid value");


        } else {
            listingNumber = newListingNumber;


       }
```

//something that prints asking price. I suspect I am just getting null because of the"void" i typted?

```
public void printDetails (){
        System.out.println("MLS Number: "+ listingNumber);
    }
```

My output :

> MLS Number: null

Comment: Your code doesn't show at what point you actually call the method to set `listingNumber` a value. E.g. `A0_Realtor main = new A0_Realtor("value");`; setting the value in the constructor or calling `setListingNumber("value")` method

Comment: It seems you have accidentally reversed your conditions. `if( newListingNumber != null || newListingNumber.isEmpty()){` mentions the first two conditions for a *valid* parameter, so that is not where you should print `Invalid value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you seem to have messed up your code by having the method `setListingNumber` inside itself.  I am guessing this is just a posting error.

But the problem is with this code

```
if( newListingNumber != null && newListingNumber.isEmpty())
```

It is not possible for the value to be `null` and `empty`.  You need to change to `or`

```
if( newListingNumber != null || newListingNumber.isEmpty())
```

**edit**

Also, you code does not show, but I am assuming that you do have a field called `listingNumber`

Comment: Thanks for your post, yes I made a posting error and forgot to add the field private String listingNumber;. I made the change to the code but I am stilling getting MLS Number: null

Comment: Please change your code so shows [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)